# Adding RDF triple using property stored in a python Dictionary

Tags: python, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, rdflib

I've been working with DBpedia for a GSoC project. I have to create triples using properties that are stored in another file.

For eg. my main file is `main.py` and the file with all the rules is `rules.py`.

Here's what I'm trying to/want to do:

**rules.py**

```
mapping_rules = {
    'family': 'relatedTo',
    'singer': 'MusicalArtist',
    'writer': 'Author'
}
```

**main.py**

```
import rules
import rdflib

dbo = rdflib.Namespace("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/")
dbr = rdflib.Namespace("http://dbpedia.org/resource/")

uri = "something"
res = "something"
p = mapping_rules[input()]
g.add((rdflib.URIRef(uri), dbo.p, rdflib.URIRef(res)))
```

I want the property of the triple to be decided dynamically.

If I use `'dbo.relatedTo'`as value in `mapping_rules.py`, it shows error: `Predicate dbo.related must be an rdflib term.`

If I use `dbo.relatedTo` as value in `mapping_rules.py`, it throws name error: `dbo is not defined.`

If I use `relatedTo` in `mapping_rules.py` and use the above code, it adds a triple, but the property becomes `dbo:p`, whereas I wanted `dbo:relatedTo`.

I'm stuck here, Can anyone help?
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried `dbo[p]` as in [this example](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_creating_rdf.html#an-example)? P.S. l'm not familiar with Python :).

Comment: @StanislavKralin Yes, that did the trick! Thank you so much!! P.S you can write this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, look at [this example](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_creating_rdf.html#an-example).

Your code should be:

```python
import rules
import rdflib

dbo = rdflib.Namespace("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/")
dbr = rdflib.Namespace("http://dbpedia.org/resource/")

uri = "something"
res = "something"
p = mapping_rules[input()]
g.add((rdflib.URIRef(uri), dbo[p], rdflib.URIRef(res)))
```

Please note that `dbo[p]` is used instead of `dbo.p`. Your problem is not rdflib-specific, but rather related to working with Python objects.